# Compiling On Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, programming

Is it possible to compile on on ubuntu server using vim and g++? and possibly uploading those files onto your ubuntu desktop using ubuntu one? I have an old mac laptop I want to use for my programming only, it is pretty old so i would rather run a cmd on it rather than an entire OS. Or if anyone has other suggestions that would be great as well, this is just a mobile lap top that i carry with me and would be great if i can upload all the work on it to my main machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the build-essential package contents, taken from http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/build-essential,
the package build-essential contains the following:

- dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5)
  Debian package development tools
- **g++ (>= 4:4.4.3)
  GNU C++ compiler** (This is what you want for C++ compilations)
- gcc (>= 4:4.4.3)
  GNU C compiler
- libc6-dev
  Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
  or libc-dev
  virtual package provided by libc6-dev
- make
  An utility for Directing compilation.

By installing this package you will be able to use the GNU C and C++ compilers. So nothing can stop you from compiling code.

Note that there is a packaged version of build-essentials for every Ubuntu version.

Vim does not depends of UI components and runs using the terminal window.

As for other lightweight recommendations for an old machine, it depends of the specs of the machine.

You can check the following window managers - desktop environments if meet your requirements:

- [LXDE](http://lxde.org/)‎
- [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/)
- [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/)
- [IceWM](http://www.icewm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I compeletely understand what you mean. Where does Ubuntu server run? On the laptop or on the desktop? I guess you want to install Ubuntu server on the laptop, right?

Anyway, if that is the case, then yes, you can compile from Ubuntu server. For most cases installing the `build-essential` package will install everything you need to compile a c++ application. Of course, you may need to install more libraries, e.g. if you are writing a GUI application.

As for getting the files back to your desktop, why not try using sshfs or NFS? I guess ubuntu one would also work, but I've not tried to use it on a command line only setup.

Comment: Yes it is a laptop, I have my main machine which is a desktop. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You may also want to look into `distcc`, which allows you to work from your desktop, but lets the laptop help in compiling. See for example http://left404.com/2013/01/12/speeding-up-builds-with-distcc-on-ubuntu/ for instructions.